# Loading file from application .ear deployed on weblogic

Tags: java, maven, weblogic

I'm trying to write code that will load *.html file from application .ear and display it. The structure of my application is:

```
application
-src
  -main
    -java
      -my.package.few.folders
        -Class.java
    -webapp
      -my.html
```

I'm new in Java and weblogic so I'm not able to figure it out by myself and all threads I found in internet are mostly the same. File should be accessible using:

```
Class.class.getClassLoader().getResource("main/webapp/my.html");
```

The problem is that my application is deployed on weblogic and above code gives me path to a weblogic domain (not my application ear where are *.html files). So using this code I'm always getting null pointer exception because .ear is hidden inside few folders in weblogic domain. I want to avoid giving specified path to .ear in weblogic, because it need to work on different servers and with only managed server name changed it will crash. How can I get straight into my .ear, not through weblogic domain?

Comment: When you load a resource (your html file) you load it from the classpath, not from the file system. Then, your code should look like this : 
Class.class.getClassLoader().getResource("my.package.few.folders.my.html");

Comment: But "my.html" is in different folder than "Class.java" so how when I enter "my.package.few.folders" how can I get to "webapp" folder? When I've tried to do:
`System.out.println(Class.class.getClassLoader().getResource("my.package.few.folders"));`
the output was "null".